# R: x-axis labeling in ggplot2 creates space gaps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code to plot a graph in R.

```
orig_vec <-c( 1.6666667 , -2.6666667 , -0.6666667 ,  1.0000000 ,  0.0000000 ,  2.3333333  , 2.3333333  , 2.6666667  , 1.6666667   ,1.6666667 ,  1.0000000  , 1.0000000  , 1.3333333  , 1.3333333 ,  1.3333333 ,
              1.3333333 , 1.3333333 ,  1.3333333  , 1.3333333  , 2.3333333 ,  2.3333333  , 1.3333333  , 1.6666667  ,-7.3333333  ,-2.6666667  ,-2.6666667 , -1.3333333 , -1.3333333 , -2.6666667  ,-2.3333333 ,
              -30.3333333 , -1.3333333 ,-5.6666667, -10.6666667 , -4.3333333,-12.3333333 , -5.3333333  ,-4.0000000, -12.0000000,  -2.6666667)
new_vec <- numeric(2 * length(orig_vec))
new_vec[seq(1, length(new_vec), by = 2)] <- orig_vec

rownames_list<-c("A0A075","P01859","P13645","P13645","P36578","P39023","P39023","P39023","P62241","P62241","P62241","P62241","P62829","P62854","P62854","P62910","P62979","P62979","P62979","P62979",
                   "P62979","Q02543","Q9NP64","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3","Q9Y3Z3")

df_v_hyp6 <- data.frame(
  Group = factor(rep(1:40,each=2)),
  Value = new_vec,
  RowName = rep(rownames_list,each=2)
)


ggplot(df_v_hyp6, aes(x = Group, y = Value, color = Value)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +  
  labs(x = "Proteins", y = "Mean differences") +
  ggtitle("Mean differences between Vehicle vs Hypoxia - 6hrs") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8,angle = 90, hjust = 1),  
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
```

The output plot is:
[image]

Instead of the x-axis labels being 1,2,...,40, I want them to be the 'RowName' variable from the data.frame.

So, I run the code:

```
ggplot(df_v_hyp6, aes(x = RowName, y = Value, color = Value)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +  
  labs(x = "Proteins", y = "Mean differences") +
  ggtitle("Mean differences between Vehicle vs Hypoxia - 6hrs") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8,angle = 90, hjust = 1),  
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
```

But this somehow widens the plotting columns and the entire plot is not shown.

[image]

I have tried `aspect.ratio=1/10`, I have tried ggsave with large width. Nothing has worked.

How do I put the names of the column 'RowName' as x-axis labels but show the entire plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that for each `RowName` there are multiple `Group`s. As a consequence your plot shows all the data but all the `Group`s corresponding to one `RowName` are plotted on top of each other.

If you want to show all `Group`s but use the `RowName` as x-axis label then you could do so via the `labels=` argument of `scale_x_discrete`. To this end create a (named) vector of labels which assigns the `RowName` to the `Group`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

x_labels <- df_v_hyp6 |> 
  dplyr::distinct(Group, RowName) |> 
  tibble::deframe()

ggplot(df_v_hyp6, aes(x = Group, y = Value, color = Value)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = x_labels) +
  labs(x = "Proteins", y = "Mean differences") +
  ggtitle("Mean differences between Vehicle vs Hypoxia - 6hrs") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      size = 8, angle = 90, hjust = 1
    ),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")
  )
```

[image]